# Stop PHP form submission from redirecting to different page

Tags: php, webforms, postback

I need to remove the code at the bottom of this form submit but when I remove the code it breaks the form.
I want the form to submit without redirecting to a html page.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "rmcgroarty@xzamcorpresults.com";
    $email_subject = "Customer From XzamCorpResults";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['phone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_to."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

***<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting XzamCorp. We are looking forward to speaking with you about your inquiry, we will contact you as soon as possible.

<?php
}
?>***

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<p align="right">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input class="text" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="Name..." onfocus="if(this.value=='Name...')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Name...';" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input class="text" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Email..." onfocus="if(this.value=='Email...')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email...';" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input class="text" type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="Phone..." onfocus="if(this.value=='Phone...')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Phone...';" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<textarea rows="10" cols="10" type="text" name="comments" id="comments" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your Feedback...')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your Feedback...';" >Your Feedback...</textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you point out the specific block you are trying to remove?

Comment: at the very bottom of the page the start and end points are marked with ***

Comment: well you cant remove it because of that closing brace in the PHP bit that comes last. Remove the other stuff and you should be fine.

Comment: the problem is when i delete any of that stuff it causes a syntax error. I just dont want the form to redirect when you push submit. That is all I am trying to stop.

Comment: I don't know why your post was down-voted without a comment, considering you're fairly new to SO, but I up-voted it back to zero for you. I think the reason was that this question has been asked multiple times before, even though you didn't really understand the problem well enough to know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant remove that code because of that closing brace between the PHP tags that come after your success HTML. You should be fine if you remove the other stuff.

**Note:** If you want to continue displaying the success message when the email is sent, but WITHOUT the redirection, ignore the changes that I made in the following code block, and make the changes that I mentioned in my Update, at the bottom.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "rmcgroarty@xzamcorpresults.com";
    $email_subject = "Customer From XzamCorpResults";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['phone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_to."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

}
?>
```

The above should work fine.

**UPDATE**

Here is what you want to do - somewhere on the page with the form, insert the following into your PHP code:

```
include("send_form_email.php");
```

Then change your `<form>` tag to the following:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="">
```

and it will post back to the same page. If you want your success message to display, but only on successful sending of an email, use the original code that you posted, not my edited code in the large code block, above.

Comment: ok I changed it to the above and it does work fine but it still loads the actual .php file in the browser showing a blank screen instead of a success message.

Comment: here take a look http://www.xzamcorpresults.com/company/results.php its the form on the right side

Comment: I just want the form to submit without anything happening to the browser

Comment: That is because of code on a different page. Post your full code (HTML included) for the page with the form on it, because that is where the issue is.

Comment: I added the html form code the very bottom of the original post. btw tyvm for your help.

Comment: No worries - I have a simple solution for you. I will make an update to my post in a moment.

Comment: I need to call host gator as my plesk login is down, I will update you hopefully soon

Comment: well unless i am completely retarded and that is possible the form is no longer sending emails atall.

Comment: I changed the form code to yours and added include the .php code you gave me on line 3 of the php form. Maybe i mis read your instructions?

Comment: ok btw i am retarded. I reread your instuctions about 20 times then I realized you meant the webpage php file not the form php file. IT WORKS AND I AM NOW YOUR MAN LOVER FOR LIFE!!! But in all seriousness. Thank you so so so much man.

Comment: No worries - please up-vote and/or accept if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just to clarify "`include("send_form_email.php");`" goes on the page with the form, between `<script></script>` Thanks!

This problem has been bugging me for a bit, see here: candu-projects.org